# How to move a large structure in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I tried to use the `/structure save` command but it did not work, because it stated that it was too big of a section to save.
Is there any other command that I could use to do it all at once?

Comment: How big is this structure?

Comment: well I did some researched and found out the max size for the structure command is 64 by 256 by 64 it is probably not higher than 256  but it is more than 70 by 100 I try to get more information on the structure size I will just have to get ahold of the owner of the map? But Diehe that was a good thing you asked me because I would have not thought of putting that in the post. Thanks and will try to get the information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I, personally would recommend using multiple structure blocks, (acquired with `/give @s structure_block 1 0`) and then set the size at maximum and place them strategically inside of, and around your structure. As long as you are in creative mode, you can press your "Use button" (usually right click or LT/L2) on the structure blocks, to see a preview of the blocks to clone.

After saving it, you may move to a separate location and arrange the structure blocks in the same orientations, and load the saved schematics in the correct order.

### ALTERNATE METHOD

You could also run `/clone {first coord} {second coord} {coords to move to}` If you do not want to use Structure blocks. The /clone command does not work over super long distances.

Comment: Note if you are trying the clone approach that target block will be used as the lower northwest corner of the cloned region. This always throws me off as I expect the target to be relative to the first coordinate entered, and it's not.